# Action class called twice from IE and not firefox

Tags: java, internet-explorer, firefox, struts

I have an application where an absolutely normal link (like below).. when clicked, calls the action class twice. And this behaviour happens only in IE. In Firefox, when i click on the same link, it calls the action class only once.

```
<a href="FileListAction.do"  title="Load"  target="_parent" id="c">Load</a>
```

This is an older application and im using Struts 1.3 and Tiles.
Any idea why this is happening and/or how it can be troubleshooted?

Comment: It could be that IE is preloading the link. Log the time when the request is received. Load the page, wait ~10 seconds, and click the link. If the difference between the log entries is ~10 seconds, it's a preload. Try making sure the link to your servlet is not the first link in the page.

Comment: Devon, The link I posted is not the first link on the page. However, this behaviour happens with every link on the page. Could you please explain a little more about pre loading and how to test it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that IE is <strike>preloading</strike> [prefetching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_prefetching) the link.

To verify this, log the time when the request is received. Load the page, wait ~10 seconds, and click the link. If the difference between the log entries is ~10 seconds, it's a prefetch.

The idea is the browser preloads links the user is likely to click, so the result can be server immediately form the browser cache.

HTML5 makes this explicit by defining `rel="prefetch"`. This attribute and value can be set on `a`, `area`, and `link` tags.

Check your page for `<link rel="prefetch" href="url" />` or `<link rel="next" href="url" />` in the `HEAD` element. Also, check your `A` tags for `rel` attributed as well.

MicroSoft claims to [officially support this in IE 11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

All of this is intended to make pages appear more responsive to the user. Where this can fall apart is when the page being retrieved is not cacheable. This will cause the page to be fetched again when the user clicks it. This can be improved by taking steps to make sure the result cacheable. Set appropriate [cache headers](http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/). There is a `Private` cache control for content that is intended for a single recipient. It's only stored in private caches, typically the user's browser.

Additionally, your page may not be considered cacheable if it does not provide a `Content-length` header.